# mat-horizontal-stepper not accepting style for the active step

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to give some style for the active tab in the header (different background color)
but nothing influencing it. how can I do it?
[the active and not active with the same color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJgf2.png)

```
`
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear id="stepper" [selectedIndex]="currentIndex" (selectionChange)="onStepChange($event)">
               
                       <ng-template matStepperIcon="done">
                      </ng-template>
                      <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
                     </ng-template>
                     <mat-step-header role="tab" aria-selected="true">
                        <mat-step>
                        </mat-step>
                     </mat-step-header> 
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
 

.mat-step-header[aria-selected="true"] { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important }
 .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected {
  background-color: #6cb73a;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work due to style encapsulation, since  is a child component of . This means styles won't "pierce down" to the header.

You can add class to your `mat-stepper` and style it by applying the styling in global `styles.scss` file.
Component template:

```
<mat-stepper linear class="my-stepper">
    <!--Contents here-->
</mat-stepper>
```

styles.scss

```
.my-stepper {
  .mat-step-icon-selected {
    color: green;
    background-color: orange;
  }

  .mat-step-label-selected {
    background-color: blue;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqwcxy).

Note that instead of overwriting material styling, you're probably better off creating your own stepper based on the angular CDK (upon which the `mat-stepper` is based). You can find the docs [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/overview).